# parse comma separated data in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help with parsing my data,

I have CSV data like this:

```
 INPUT.csv
 col0  col1    col2    col3     col4
 blue,  eight,  line,    aaa     abc@123.com,xyz@123.com,ghi@123.com
 green, nine,   square,  bbb     sdf@123.com,wef@123.com,hft@123.com
```

1)I want to parse data with comma's under col4, and write to new columns col5 and col6 
2) i am concatenating col1,col2 and col3, i want to prefix PR# before the concatenated output for every line

ie. My expected result should be

```
 OUTPUT.csv
  col0      col1                 col4          col5           col6
  blue   PR# eight line   aaa    abc@123.com   xyz@123.com    ghi@123.com
  green  PR# nine  square bbb    sdf@123.com   wef@123.com    hft@123.com
```

My code so far:

```
 import csv

 with open('INPUT.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
 csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

with open('OUTPUT.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
    fieldnames = ['col0','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file,lineterminator='\n' , 
  fieldnames=fieldnames)
   )

     for row in csv_reader:                    
     csv_writer.writerow({
        "col0": row["col0"],
        "col1": row["col1"] + row["co2"] +  row["3"],
        "col4": row["col4"]  
       })
```

Comment: any suggestions for  2) i am concatenating col1,col2 and col3, i want to prefix PR# before the concatenated output for every line

Comment: "col4":row["col4"].split(",")[0], ## works fine

Comment: "col4":row["col4"].split(",")[1],  ## has error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: any suggestion please